# How to determine the cardinality for this question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I just learned about elementary set theory material but I have difficulty answering this question
(Note: this is not a homework question)

Here's the question

Determine the **cardinality** of each of the following sets.

(a). A = {x ∈ N : (100 ≤ x ≤ 1000 000 000 000) Λ (x is a multiple of 60)}.

(b). B = {x ∈ N : (100 ≤ x ≤ 1000 000 000 000) Λ (x is a multiple of 75)}.

(c). A ∩ B.

(d). A ∪ B.

(e). A ⊕ B.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

1. An easier question may be, how many multiples of 60 are there in $[1,N]$ for some large $N$? Imagine enumerating them: $\{60, 120, 180, \ldots\}$ or equivalently $\{60\cdot 1, 60 \cdot 2, 60 \cdot 3, \ldots\}$. Now the answer is clear: there are $n$ numbers in $[1,N]$ which are multiples of 60, where $n$ is the largest possible integer such that $60n \leq N$. When $N$ is itself a multiple of 60, that number is $n = N/60$. For a general $N$, you have to round down: $n = \lfloor N/60 \rfloor$.
2. Then, to answer "how many multiples of 60 are in $[a, b]$?" Notice it is the same as however many multiples of 60 are in $[1,b]$, minus however many multiples of 60 are in $[1, a-1]$.
3. Similarly for 75.
4. One can compute $|A\cap B|$ in a similar way, by asking: when is a number a multiple of BOTH 60 and 75? Think about prime factorization/least common multiple.
5. Then, to find $|A\cup B|$, try the inclusion-exclusion principle
6. As for $A \oplus B$, I do not know off the top of my head, partially because I am unsure of the notation. Do you mean $\{a + b : a\in A \text{ and } b\in B\}$? If so, take a look at [the coin problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: $A\oplus B$ may mean the symmetric difference $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A),$ in which case that problem can be solved using the same method as the others.